# Question on a 2-Level page table operation

Tags: architecture, operating-system, page-tables

My questions are added in the picture, because it's more clear for you to see! [this is the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivgDF.png)

[This is the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATQFl.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following uses terms & sizes from i386, which is typical of a forward mapped page table architecture.
The code below is illustrative of the steps the cpu makes to fetch from a virtual address:

```
typedef struct {
       unsigned valid:1, perm:11, paddr:20;
} pte;
unsigned pg_offset(va) { return va & 4095; }
unsigned lo_index(va)  { return (va >> 12) & 1023; }
unsigned hi_index(va)  { return (va >> 22) & 1023; }

paddr_t vtop(va) {
      pte temp, *pte;
      pte = (pte *)GetCr3();
      temp = pte[hi_index(va)];
      if (temp.valid /* other checks too */) {
           pte = (pte *)(temp.paddr * 4095);
           temp = pte[lo_index(va)];
           if (temp.valid /* other checks too */) {
                return temp.paddr * 4095 + pg_offset(va);
           }
       }
       raise_pagefault_exception();
}
```

So, in your questions:
The offset is not 2c, because that is the offset applied to the final translation; the one you are pointing at is the first translation, which only
uses bits 22..31 of the va.

The upper address bits selected entry 1 from the table, which happens to have a physical address of 1, not 3.   3 has nothing to do with this translation at all.

P likely refers to present (or valid) indicating that this page table entry is valid.

Because that is what the indices from the address produce; if it were a different address, it might produce different indices.   The book author could have made a much better example, perhaps featuring some distinct indices.   One day, you can do better.